# Postfix Configuration files

Tags: linux, postfix, redhat, email-server

Kindly find your help on th below :)

I am about to install postfix 2.10.2 on my RHEL server 5.9

I'll do this via source code.

I need to reconfigure paths in main.cf,

Example: /etc/postfix -> /smtp/postfix

And so on with queue directory,...etc

Idea: Put all configuration and logs under one directory.

So, Is that valid ????

Also, If this is Valid, Is that better to change paths in main.cf before installation or after it ???

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Well I suppose it's really your (or your client's) problem, but standards and conventions exist for a reason. Could you share the reason why you need/want to do something unconventional like this? Without the reason we could not really tell if your approach is valid or not...

Comment: 1- I did, Thanks 2- Customer needs to organize configuraion files and logs -- we'll have parent directory /smtp -- under it /postfix --> which will contain [ main.cf, master.cf, .. so on ] -- also we've /spool/postfix/logs --> contains mail server logs -- aliases They need every thing in one place

Comment: "One place" can mean under one directory tree, not necessarily in one directory. If the customer is not file system savvy it is doubtful they can give you useful direction at this detailed level. That is where a consultant's expertise comes into play. Don't ask questions about implementation. Ask questions about requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This seems wrong on so many levels. You are making it more difficult to maintain (by installing from source you lose all upstream QA and updates) and you are moving things around that don't need to move around.

Is it valid?  Yes. You can make it work.  Should you so this?  Probably not.

Comment: Agreed. The OP might have a good reason to do something like that, but at this time we have not heard anything compelling...

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly *possible* to place the Postfix configuration and log files wherever you want. The `-c` option for Postfix allows the configuration directory to be moved and most (all?) other file paths can be configured in `main.cf`.

Just install Postfix normally and then move or copy-over the configuration wherever you want, preferrably in conjunction with a revision control system so that any future upgrades will not mess up your setup without possibility of recovery. You may then have to modify the launch scripts to have them look in the right place.

Whether or not it is *advisable* to do something like this, however, would depend on the specifics of your situation. In general it is preferred to work along common conventions, rather than against them. That said, it is of course your job to advise your client, but I suppose in the end whatever they say goes...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you're telling me to install normally then move, but here we come to important question.
We've variable in main.cf caller queue_directory which determines path of directory which will contain [ main , master, access, .. so on ]..

Your approach is simply i'll copy these files after installation to the place I need.
My approach is that, Install postfix, change path of queue_directory in main.cf which will be under /etc/postfix by default, run postfix reload.
Please, Advise on this and if my approach is right, Better to do this after/before installation ?

Comment: note: I took queue_directory as example

Comment: @DeepoOoOoz: 1 sec. Why would you need `postfix reload`? Is there already a version of Postfix on this server?

Comment: no .. but i read that .. if you have postfix installed and you made any change to postfix configuraion files .. you should run this.

My mind is conflicted, could you please advice with simple steps for expected action :) ?

Comment: @DeepoOoOoz: 1. Install Postfix. 2. Put everything in its final location and configure it. 3. Launch Postfix and test your setup.

Comment: @DeepoOoOoz: That said, it seems to me that you are somewhat inexperienced in Unix administration in general and setting Postfix up correctly is not a trivial task, even for seasoned administrators (although it comes nowhere near Sendmail in complexity IMHO). I would suggest going through the [Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html) - it is very extensive and quite easy to read. Unless you really understand what you are doing you run the risk of making mistakes such as bringing up an open SMTP relay on the Internet.

Comment: 1 - I installed postfix with basic settings
2 - Modified needed paths in main.cf & master.cf
3 - move all files to new destinations
4 - #postfix start  >> I've error message that no main.cf in /etc/postfix "old and basic Directory"

Could you advise on this ?
Also, how to uninstall such installations via source code.

Comment: @DeepoOoOoz: 1. Read the manual on the `-c` option to `postfix`. 2. you would be better off building a proper Postfix RPM for RHEL, rather than installing a tarball.

Comment: Can I've chat with you on skype or something :) ?

Comment: @DeepoOoOoz: Better keep everything on this site. If you have more questions, either edit your question with what you have tried and where it fails, or post a new question.